# C: Pause system() call

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, system

I got a problem in C when I try to pause an execution of a `system()` call.

A thread calls some application (e.g. some benchmark) repeatedly. Whenever it gets a signal `SIGUSR1`, the execution shall be paused and resumed on receiving `SIGUSR2`.

The source looks like this:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* run_app(sigset_t* signalsBetweenControllerandLoad)
{
    /* assign handler */
    signal(SIGUSR1, pausesignal_handler)
    signal(SIGUSR2, pausesignal_handler)
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, signalsBetweenControllerandLoad, NULL))

    /* call application repeatedly */
    while(1) {
        system(SOMECOMMAND);
    }

    return(0);
}

static void pausesignal_handler(int signo)
{
    int caughtSignal;
    caughtSignal = 0;

    /* when SIGUSR1 is received, wait until SIGUSR2 to continue execution */
    if (signo == SIGUSR1) {
        signal(signo, pausesignal_handler);

        while (caughtSignal != SIGUSR2) {
            sigwait (signalsBetweenControllerandLoad, &caughtSignal);
        }
    }
}
```

When I use some commands (e.g. a for loop as below that makes some computations) instead of `system(SOMECOMMAND)` this code works. But a program called by system() is not paused when the handler is active.

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    sleep(1);
    printf("Just a text");
}
```

Is there a way to pause the execution of the system() command by using thread signals? And is there even a way to stop the application called by system without needing to wait until the program is finished?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to present you my (shortened) resulting code after the help of @rici. Again, thank you very much.
Shortly described, the code forks a new process (calling `fork`) and executes there a command with `exec`. The parent then catches user defined signals `SIGNAL_PAUSE` and `SIGNAL_RESUME` and forwards signals to the forked child accordingly. Whenever the command finishes - catched by `waitpid` - the parent forks again and restarts the load.
This gets repeated until `SIGNAL_STOP` is sent where the child gets a `SIGINT` and gets cancelled.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIGNAL_PAUSE (SIGUSR1)
#define SIGNAL_RESUME (SIGUSR2)
#define SIGNAL_STOP (SIGSYS)

/* File scoped functions */
static void pausesignal_handler(int signo);
static void stopsignal_handler(int signo);
void send_signal_to_load_child(int signo);

/*Set file scope variables as handlers can only have signal-number as argument */
sigset_t* signalsBetweenControllerandLoad;
int restart_benchmark;
pid_t child_pid;

void* Load(char* load_arguments[MAX_NR_LOAD_ARGS], sigset_t* signalsToCatch) {
    int load_ID;
    pid_t p;

    signalsBetweenControllerandLoad = signalsToCatch;

    /* set signal handlers to catch signals from controller */
    signal(SIGNAL_PAUSE, pausesignal_handler)
    signal(SIGNAL_RESUME, pausesignal_handler)
    signal(SIGNAL_STOP, stopsignal_handler)
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, signalsBetweenControllerandLoad[load_ID], NULL)

    /* Keep restarting benchmark until Stop signal was received */
    restart_benchmark[load_ID] = 1;

    /* execute benchmark, repeat until stop signal received */
    while(restart_benchmark[load_ID])
    {
        if (child_pid == 0) {
            if ((p = fork()) == 0) {
                execv(load_arguments[0],load_arguments);
                exit(0);
            }
        }

        /* Parent process: Wait until child with benchmark finished and restart it */
        if (p>0) {
            child_pid = p;  /* Make PID available for helper functions */
            wait(child_pid);        /* Wait until child finished */
            child_pid = 0;  /* Reset PID when benchmark finished */
        }
    }

    return(0);
}

static void pausesignal_handler(int signo) {
    static double elapsedTime;
    int caughtSignal;
    caughtSignal = 0;

    if (signo == SIGNAL_PAUSE) {
        send_signal_to_load_child(SIGSTOP);
        printf("Load Paused, waiting for resume signal\n");

        while (restart_benchmark == 1 && caughtSignal != SIGNAL_RESUME) {
            sigwait (signalsBetweenControllerandLoad, &caughtSignal);
            if (caughtSignal == SIGNAL_STOP) {
                printf("Load caught stop signal when waiting for resume\n");
                stopsignal_handler(caughtSignal);
            } else if (caughtSignal != SIGNAL_RESUME) {
                printf("Load caught signal %d which is not Resume (%d), keep waiting...\n",caughtSignal,SIGNAL_RESUME);
            }
        }
        if (restart_benchmark[load_ID]) {
            send_signal_to_load_child(SIGCONT, load_ID);
            printf("Load resumed\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("Load caught unexpected signal %d.\n",signo);
    }
    /* reassign signals for compatibility reasons */
    signal(SIGNAL_PAUSE, pausesignal_handler);
    signal(SIGNAL_RESUME, pausesignal_handler);
}

static void stopsignal_handler(int signo) {
    double elapsedTime;
    signal(SIGNAL_STOP, stopsignal_handler);
    if (signo == SIGNAL_STOP) {
        restart_benchmark = 0;
        send_signal_to_load_child(SIGINT);
        printf("Load stopped.\n");
    } else {
        printf("catched unexpected stop-signal %d\n",signo);
    }
}

void send_signal_to_load_child(int signo) {
    int dest_pid;
    dest_pid = child_pid;
    printf("Error sending %d to Child: PID not set.\n",signo);
    kill(dest_pid, signo);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`system` runs the command in a separate process, which doesn't even share address space with the invoking program, never mind signal handlers. The process which called `system` is sitting in a `waitpid` (or equivalent), so pausing and unpausing it will have little effect (except that if it is paused, it won't return to the loop to call `system` again.)

In short, there is no way to use signals sent to the parent process to pause an executable being run in a child, for example with the `system()` call or with `fork()/exec()`.

If the executable itself implements the feature (which is unlikely, unless you wrote it yourself), you could deliver the signal to that process, not the one which called `system`.

Alternatively, you could send the `SIGSTOP` signal to the executable's process, which will unconditionally suspend execution. To do that, you'll need to know its pid, which suggests the use of the `fork()/exec()/waitpid()` sequence -- a little more work than `system()`, but cleaner, safer, and generally more efficient -- and you'll need to deal with a couple of issues:

- A process cannot block or trap `SIGSTOP`, but it can trap `SIGCONT` so the sequence is not necessarily 100% transparent.
- Particular care needs to be taken if the stopped process is the terminal's controlling process, since when it is resumed with `SIGCONT` it will need to reacquire the terminal. Furthermore, if the application has placed the terminal in a non-standard state -- for example, by using the `readline` or `curses` libraries which typically put the terminal into raw mode and disable echoing -- then the terminal may be rendered unusable.
- Your process will receive a `SIGCHLD` signal as a result of the child processed being stopped. So you need to handle that correctly.

Comment: Thank you! But is there another command I can replace `system` with that runs in the same process as it is called?

Comment: @IsQb: No. Executable files expect to run in their own process. You could use some sort of plugin system (dynamically loaded modules) but that involves a certain amount of work and needs to be customized for every OS since there is no standard interface; in the end, you'd need to do all the plumbing yourself. In short, there is only one `main` in any executable, by design.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but so it's impossible to e.g. call Matlab (without GUI) in the code and then interrupt / resume or close it?

Comment: @IsQb: "Impossible" is a Big Word. You could, for example, send the Matlab process a `SIGSTOP` and then later sent it `SIGCONT` to resume it. For that, you'd need to know the process's pid so you'd need to invoke it with `fork` and `exec` and then `waitpid` for it to finish, which is a bit more work than calling `system`, but in many ways safer. SIGSTOP/SIGCONT is not 100% transparent to applications since they can trap `SIGCONT`. Also, if the paused application has placed the terminal in a non-standard state, the terminal will remain in that state, which might make it unusable.